# How do I connect to an unbound table on SQL Server from VS/VB?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I created a form in Visual Studio 2012 binding table 1 to a few of the fields in order to force the user to use specific data in both a textbox and a combobox.  They select what they need out of those fields, and fill in a few others, and then click save, which will take the data to table 2.  While I've created a dataset, bindingsource, tableadapter, and tableadaptermanager for table 2, it does not save to the table if I use...

```
Me.Validate()
Me.table2BindingSource.EndEdit()
Me.table2TableAdapter.Update(table2DataSet)
```

...like you can if you use the bound source that's autofilling the form.  How do I wire the save to hit the proper table?  Do I have to go the long way and open up a connection creating the sql statement, executing that business, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did have to code the connection sequence into the button click.  I've included the code below for posterity and comment.

```
Using connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(My.Settings.MyConnectionString)
            Using Command As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table2 (stuff1, stuff2, stuff3) VALUES (@stuff1, @stuff2, @stuff3)", connection)
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stuff1", stuff1TextBox.Text)
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stuff2r", stuff2ComboBox.Text)
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stuff3", stuff3TextBox.Text)

                connection.Open()

                Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Dim rowsAffected As Integer = Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected)
            End Using
```

It worked well enough for me to be comfortable and submit it for user testing.  Please feel free to pull it apart.